# How can I solve unused code error in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I used Visual Studio Code in Unity.

When I open a script, Visual Studio Code is highlighting unused code with error. How do I solve this problem?

(Recommended: Marked as green underline as before or disabled)

```
// Example code
int a = 3;
int b = 5;
Debug.LogFormat("{0}", b);
```

> the variable 'a' is declared, but never used (CS0168)

Comment: I would solve it by not declaring variables that are not used. There's a reason those warnings exist.

Comment: Why is this a problem? You don't need the variable as you are not using it. You can just remoe it and the Warning is gone without any difference for your code.

Comment: If this wasn't an error before, which I guess you mean by _"Marked as green underline as before or disabled"_, then you probably have checked the box labeled _"Treat warnings as errors"_. Uncheck that box.

Comment: Why not comment the lines with the warnings

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove it if you are not going to use it later. Or if you still want to keep it you can use something Like this:

```
#pragma warning disable 0219
        int a = 3;
#pragma warning restore 0219
```

[image]

You can see the exact error or warning code of the message in your Error List window, and change the code 0219 to what you see there.

Comment: @TOMOU Then as CodeCaster already said, I think *you probably have checked the box labeled "Treat warnings as errors". Uncheck that box.*

Answer (score 0):

With the OP's screen shot we can see where the confusion is coming from. The CS0168 warning concerns the following line, with the red squiggle under `beforeItem`, which is obviously different than the example code given in the question:

```cs
ItemData beforeItem, currentItem;
```

Using the code style of the original question this warning can be generated with the following code - note that `a` is declared but never assigned a value:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a;
            int b = 5;
            Debug.Print("{0}", b);
        }
    }
}
```

Which yields:

```
> csc Program.cs 
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.100.19.26603 (9d80dea7)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Program.cs(9,17): warning CS0168: The variable 'a' is declared but never used
```

However the example in the original question is basically this - note that `a` is assigned the value `3` but not subsequently used:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 3;
            int b = 5;
            Debug.Print("{0}", b);
        }
    }
}
```

Which yields:

```
> csc Program.cs 
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.100.19.26603 (9d80dea7)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Program.cs(9,17): warning CS0219: The variable 'a' is assigned but its value is never used
```

Thus the confusion.

Ironically both warnings are thrown by [the same line in the Roslyn compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/FlowAnalysis/DefiniteAssignment.cs#L1649):

```cs
private void ReportIfUnused(LocalSymbol symbol, bool assigned)
{
    if (!_usedVariables.Contains(symbol))
    {
        if (symbol.DeclarationKind != LocalDeclarationKind.PatternVariable && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(symbol.Name)) // avoid diagnostics for parser-inserted names
        {
            Diagnostics.Add(assigned && _writtenVariables.Contains(symbol) ? ErrorCode.WRN_UnreferencedVarAssg : ErrorCode.WRN_UnreferencedVar, symbol.Locations[0], symbol.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

To fix the CS0168 warning, delete the definition of `a` or use:

```cs
#pragma warning disable 168
int a;
#pragma warning restore 168
```

To fix the CS0219 warning, delete the definition of `a` or use:

```cs
#pragma warning disable 219
int a = 3;
#pragma warning restore 219
```

To fix the CS0168 warning given in the screen shot delete the definition of `beforeItem` or use:

```cs
#pragma warning disable 168
ItemData beforeItem, currentItem;
#pragma warning restore 168
```

Comment: How does `0219` related to `CS0168` again?

Comment: The OP is using VSCode for Unity.

Comment: Yes, this is why, I have already mentioned *You can see the exact error or warning code of the message in your Error List window, and change the code 0219 to what you see there.*

Comment: The OP is not using Visual Studio 2019.